# PHP: unable to access default index.php in codeignitor3 using RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

The default CodeIgniter3 package is used here.
Below is the folder structure

[image]

Case1

```
   .htaccess
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule    ^backoffice?$    outtest.php    [NC,L]
```

Trigger url: http://localhost/ci/backoffice 
Output: expected output 
Case2

```
.htaccess
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule    ^backoffice?$    codeigniter/intest.php    [NC,L]
```

Trigger url: http://localhost/ci/backoffice 
Output: expected output

Case3

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^backoffice?$    codeigniter/index.php    [NC,L]
```

Trigger url: http://localhost/ci/backoffice 
Output: Wrong output

When i remove the contents of index.php and try the same it works fine.
What should i do to make this work?

Comment: case 2 and 3 are same what you want exactly?

Comment: @HikmatSijapati they don't appear same to my understanding. i'm not sure how to reply to your question. could you verify case 2 and case 3 one more time and let me know what you understood from it?

Comment: have you tried this or check this documentation of CI
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file